# WPF ObservableCollection<T> vs BindingList<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection, infragistics

In my WPF app I have a XamDataGrid.  The grid is bound to an ObservableCollection.  I need to allow users to insert new rows through the grid but it turns out that in order for the "Add New Row" row to be available, the xamDataGrid's source needs to implement IBindingList.  ObservableCollection does not implement that interface.

If I change my source to a BindingList, it works ok.  However, from what I can understand from reading up on this topic, BindingList is really a WinForms thing and is not fully supported in WPF.

Would I be making a mistake if I changed all of my ObservableCollections to BindingLists?  Does anyone have any other suggestions as to how I can get add new row functionality for my xamDataGrid while keeping the source as an ObservableCollection?  It is my understanding that there are a number of different grids that require IBindingList to be implemented in order to support add new row functionality but most solutions I see are to just switch to BindingList.

Thanks.

Comment: What is a XamDatagrid in the first place ? Do you mean the WPF toolkit datagrid ? a third party component ? Can you please also post some sample code :)

Comment: @Bruno It's Infragistic's version of a Datagrid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [IBindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx) interface and [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) class are defined in the System.ComponentModel namespace, and so are not strictly Windows Forms related.

Have you checked if [xamGrid](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/2010.3/CLR4.0/) supports binding to a [ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx) source? If so, you could expose your data sources using this interface and back it using a [BindingListCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindinglistcollectionview.aspx).

You could also create a subclass of `ObservableCollection<T>` and implement the IBindingList interface:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class ObservableBindingList<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IBindingList
{
    //  Constructors
    public ObservableBindingList() : base()
    {
    }

    public ObservableBindingList(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection)
    {
    }

    public ObservableBindingList(List<T> list) : base(list)
    {
    }

    //  IBindingList Implementation
    public void AddIndex(PropertyDescriptor property)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object AddNew()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool AllowEdit
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool AllowNew
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool AllowRemove
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public void ApplySort(PropertyDescriptor property, ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Find(PropertyDescriptor property, object key)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool IsSorted
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public event ListChangedEventHandler ListChanged;

    public void RemoveIndex(PropertyDescriptor property)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void RemoveSort()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ListSortDirection SortDirection
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public PropertyDescriptor SortProperty
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool SupportsChangeNotification
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool SupportsSearching
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool SupportsSorting
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

Alternately, you could subclass `BindingList<T>` and implement the [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) interface.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with IBindingList, but I would probably take the approach of writing an adapter and/or extension class that adapts an ObservableCollection to an IBindingList.  This way, you can keep your familiar ObservableCollection code (and also use it in other places besides the Infragistic DataGrid).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're out of luck either way.  IBindingList won't fully be supported by the grid, so you'll lose things like sorting I beleive.  But OC doesn't do the AddNew behavior.

I wouldn't use IBindingList, I'd probably just add a button to insert a new item into the list and then set the grid to edit that item.

Answer (score 0):

Would those link help  ?

http://xceed.com/CS/blogs/dontpanic/archive/2009/04/01/i-notify-we-notify-we-all-wait-no-we-don-t.aspx (very useful even if tagged as "Xceed" ;)

[ObservableCollection(Of T) vs BindingList(Of T)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455284/observablecollectionof-t-vs-bindinglistof-t)

Answer (score 0):

If you can upgrade to NetAdvantage 2011 Volume 2 the add new record will work when bound to an ObservableCollection.

If you are using NetAdvantage 2011 Volume 1 or older, then the XamDataGrid also supports the IEditableCollectionView interface when its CanAddNew property returns true.  You could use a ListCollectionView giving it the instance of your ObservableCollection and then bind the XamDataGrid to the ListCollectionView.

You could also use the previous suggestion of deriving from ObservableCollection and implementing IBindingList on your derived class.

Comment: I have upgraded to v11.2 but it still does not work. When replacing OC with BL it works again. Is there any setting I have to set?

Comment: @marek The only setting that should be necessary is AllowAddNew set to True on the FieldLayoutSettings which is needed whether you use a BindingList<T> or an ObservableCollection<T>.  I tested this with 11.2 this morning and the AddNewRow works with an ObservableCollection.  If you can provide a sample that I can look at where it doesn't work I will take a look.