# Bind a datagrid one object per cell

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I would like to bind some objects to a `datagrid` in `WPF`. I would VERY MUCH like to avoid DataTable!

Consider the following code:

```
public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<DataPoint>> GridItems { get; set; }

public class DataPoint : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public float Value { get; set; }
    public float OriginalValue { get; set; }
    public bool Highlighted { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush HighlightColor { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

XAML:

```
<toolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems}" />
```

When we bind this to a `DataGrid` instead of getting one DataPoint object per cell we get one column with `Count` as the property shown.  I have tried 2D arrays, custom types (inheriting from `ObservableCollection<DataPoint>`), `HierarchicalDataTemplate` but nothing seems to be working.

I do not know before-hand how many columns there are going to be, but it will always be the same number and type for every row. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you AutoGenerating these columns?

Comment: How did you solve your problem based on _Brian S_ answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider your `ItemsSource`, an `ObservableCollection` of `ObservableCollection`s, then you will recognize that the each row in the grid is just an `ObservableCollection` object.  The `DataGrid` is not smart enough to look inside of the collection at each item  (and it doesn't make sense - there might be a different number of items in each collection, so it can't automatically map the items to columns).  It will just look at the object that is the `DataContext` for the row and use the public properties as columns (in this case, the only property of `ObservableCollection` that qualifies is `Count`)

EDIT: I just remembered the [`IBindingList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx) interface, which allows for a more complex binding scenario (I believe this is how the `DataTable` can expose the columns as properties for binding purposes.  Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254441/wpf-observablecollectiont-vs-bindinglistt) for information on `IBindingList` and how it may prove useful.  You may be able to create a custom class that derives from `ObservableCollection` and implements `IBindingList` to expose the DataPoints as properties.

original:

Since you don't know how many columns there will be, you can't declaratively databind them through XAML.  I believe you're going to need to manually create the columns in code and set the Binding for each column.

Also, you'll need a `DataTemplate` for the DataPoint type so that it knows how to visually display the type.